How do I increase I2C/Wire Timeout on Teensy41
I am working on an I2C system with a Teensy41 master and an Adruino NANO as a slave.
It currently takes the NANO about 700 microseconds to do a calculation and reply to the request for data from master. Most of that time is not the calculation it is just copying the data to a buffer. But every now and then the time to prepare the message is higher (over 1 milisecond?) and the I2C master appears to timeout.
Is there a way to increase the timeout on the Teensy I2C libraty? (The version of Wire that Teensy uses does not have the setWireTimeout() function)
Is 700 microseconds on the NANO ATmega328 reasonable for copying a few 10's of bytes to the buffer and sending on I2C, or is this ripe for optimisation? (there is at least 2 buffers involved, mine and then at least one inside the Wire library so the data is copied several times)

If I remember correctly, a typical way to handle this is for the master to ask the slave if the data is ready to be read.  It may need to ask several times until it is.  This could also be called retrieving a status byte from the slave.  Of course, this type of thing needs to be part of the communication protocol, and you'd need to develop the code to do it.  It should be no issue using only the most basic libraries.

I2C master appears to timeout ... what does that mean?  ... does it time out or not?

Wire internal buffer is 32-bytes, if you have timeout problem, it is more often is that your code cause it or block it instead of the i2c communication need longer than the timeout. So instead of trying to change the timeout, you should review your code to see how to improve it.

I hope you all realize that the link needs some handshake algorithm, and the code needs to be changed on both ends of the communication link.

Find your wireIMXRT.cpp file.line 139.

OK. I2C is a steep learning curve. In the hope that it might be useful to others facing the same issues I'll post an answer here with some of the things I learned.
In getting up the I2C learning curve I basically made 2 mistakes:

Don't over do any roll-your-own error checking, I2C is actually very reliable, way more reliable than you might imagine from reading various articles online.

Don't try to calculate data on the fly in the slave. Design your program so that when the master requests data from the slave the data is pre-prepared. Only ever return pre-prepared data, don't rely on calculating anything on the slave between the master sending a message and requesting a response.


Lessons learned:

I2C comms is pretty fast when it is working well. You don't want timeouts happening regularly, they will slow things down by 1000 times. So my original question above was heading in the wrong direction. See below about pre-prepared data and fast interrupt handlers.

When I finally got it working I2C was very reliable. Even with off board wires way longer than recommended, no shielding and with high current conductors going through the same connector as the I2C signals there was virtually no data corruption. So don't go overboard adding roll-your-own error checking. Lots of the problems I encountered were due to misinterpreting advice on how unreliable I2C is and how you need lots of checksums, readbacks, result codes and status bits etc. All of that advice is valid if it is done in the right way. But in practice the reliability is very high so, depending on your application, you can live without much of those checks, and, no matter what your application, misinterpreting all that advice about adding checks will cause lots of problems.

You have to read up a bit on interrupts. I2C relies on interrupts and the handler functions that you write are called by interrupts. So you need to know the basic do's and don'ts. In short do the minimum amount of data copying and state manipulation in the handler functions and try to do as little else as possible. The functions have to be fast with minimum computations and importantly nothing that triggers another interrupt part way through execution. Beyond all else if the onRecieve() handler is still running when the onRequest() handler is called then you are not doing it right.

Design your program so that there are 2 types of transactions. command and data request.



When the master sends a command then execute the command on the slave
but don't try to return the results of the command in the same
transaction. Store the results as preprepared data that the master
can request in a later transaction.

When the master requests data then design the program so that the
data is pre-prepared. Whether it is sensor data or the result of a
previous command or something else, make sure it is pre-prepared and
buffered and just send it back immediately. Don't try to calculate it
in response to the request.



In the end the only error checks I inserted in the messaging was a checksum and an implicit way of checking the expected message length based on the value of the first byte of the message. Things like command byte readbacks, result codes and status flags fall into the category of pre-prepared data that can be requested after a command is sent (not returned in the same transaction).

Tend towards 'fire-and-forget' rather than 'handshaking' in the design. At the message level my final working code was very much fire and forget. In particular avoid any design where the master expects to send a command and get any acknowledgement or response code or any output data in the same transaction. This approach guarantees speed and avoids timeouts. Reliability was established over several messages. If a message failed its checksum at the slave end the slave set the result byte accordingly. If the master cared to check it could request the result byte in a subsequent transaction. If a message failed a checksum at the master end the master could simply request the same data again.


